# How Rails 'resources' fetch data from tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, resources

How exactly Rails 'resources' fetch data from tables ? Where the query for CRUD is written ?
Could anyone explain how the database connectivity happen?

Comment: Please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying to clarify some things:

1. The queries for CRUD are abstracted in **Active Record** methods. Take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) to know more.
2. The [database connectivity](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database) is defined in your `config/database.yml` configuration by default.
3. The `resources` that is defined in the `routes` file just set up the CRUD routes for a model.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful !